# a webRtc Clearing View

Tags: signalr, webrtc

i'm a newbie to webRTC and  their is some stuff that i did not get if it was possible i would like an answer to those question and i quiet think that it will be a good reference to all the other guys over the web .

1. webRTC server code witch left to be handle by the developer what is it job ? i mean their is a lot of signaling method using websocket and socket.io but what did they send to the server ? .
2. i see some github sources in may learning path that provide these "id" i'm wondering does the server code provide these id  and what is it job ?.
3. i did not get how i can share video conf in real base scenario .. any concret example explanation ?.
4. i'm wondering if i can use a combination of signalR and webRTC . is is possible thus signlaR provide real time communication and data delivering and the webRTC provide many many services like video conf .. audio .. data exchange .. etc . and is it a valid server code ? .

Answer (score 0):

1) The server-side differs depending on the method used for signalling. For WebRTC specifically, because any browser that supports WebRTC will also support WebSocket, WebSocket is the likely candidate to be used for the signalling method.

Now, the server-side for WebSocket can be somewhat complex, as you have to first handle the handshake to elevate the protocol to either ws or wss, and after that, you have to handle the encrypting and decrypting of all messages sent over the line via WebSocket. This is not trivial at all, but if you do some searching around SO and the web in general for information about how to code the server-side for WebSocket, you should be able to find what you're looking for.

2) I can't understand what you're asking in this question. Could you please provide an example/link? Thanks.

3) You use WebRTC to establish a peer-to-peer connection between two clients to quickly transfer data back and forth. One benefit of this peer-to-peer connection (and the speed at which you can transfer data) is the ability to establish video connections. Also, you can establish video links between more than two clients at a time, although with too many connections, there can be bandwidth issues.

What specifically do you want to know about how to use this technology for video conferencing?

4) I'm not too familiar with SignalR, but looking at the home page, SignalR is used to push data from the server. WebRTC doesn't use a server at all (once the peer-to-peer connection has been established). By that rationale, WebRTC will likely always provide a better, faster connection than SignalR.

Please clarify some of your questions as noted above, and I will help in any way I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer number 4...
You can of course use SignalR to do the signaling between clients to get WebRTC running, but SignalR has no built-in functionality for the WebRTC signaling so you are in for a pretty nasty job if you are planning on doing it your self.

Since you are asking about SignalR I am jumping to conclusions here and guess that you are a .NET developer? If so there are .NET libraries out there that already have taken care of the signaling for you. One of them is [XSockets.NET](http://XSockets.NET).

Just install the [sample package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XSockets.Sample.WebRTC) from XSockets and you will have a multi video chat up and running in a minute.

Sorry for not answering 1,2 and 3... But I hope that the package from XSockets will solve these quesitons :)